# Lulav and Sukkah on Shemini Atzeres

Tags: halacha, sukkah, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shmini-atzeres

If you have the minhag to eat in the Sukkah on Shmini Atzeres, why is there no minhag to take the lulav (without a bracha) on Shmini Atzeres?